# Assign rank for each group by each date in pandas data frame - not getting expected rank value

Tags: python, pandas, ranking, rank

need help.
i have a sample data which contains sessionid and datetime visited. one session may be visited multiple pages in the same day. i need to assign ranking for each date group by the session.

sample
[image]

the code which i am using is

```
   df['date_rank'] = df.groupby(['CookieID'])['PageViewDate'].rank().astype(int)
```

but it is not giving expected rank

the output is

[image]

Comment: Is `CookieID` an existing column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use the [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) method instead of [`rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) :

```py
df['date_rank'] = df.groupby(['CookieID'])['PageViewDate'].cumcount() + 1
```